# C++ int or float to char array

Tags: c++, mbed

I'm trying to convert a integer or a float to a char array, in a specific form (programming for mbed, a micro-controller).

The integers should be 32-bit big-endian two's complement integer
The floats should be 32-bit big-endian IEEE 754 floating point number

Tried a few things:

```
uint8_t *v;
uint8_t valuePos = 3;
v = (uint8_t *)datum->data.i; //I get the int or float from datum->data.i
buff[lengthEnd++] = v[valuePos--]; //buff is the char array
buff[lengthEnd++] = v[valuePos--];
buff[lengthEnd++] = v[valuePos--];
buff[lengthEnd++] = v[valuePos];
```

and

```
uint32_t i = BigEndian(datum->data.i);
uint8_t * ptr = (uint8_t *) &i;
strcat(buff, (char *) ptr); //maybe strcat isn't a good function to use here
lengthEnd += 4;
```

But I can't make it work, I always get some other number. What is going wrong?

Comment: Hi, the first example worked in a previous adaptation from another OSC class. Now reworking the whole thing and now it gives the value  2015428624 instead of 123.
The second part of code was from another OSC class for arduino, but instead of strcat it used p.write( .... ).

Will look at the stringstream how i can use that

Comment: @H2CO3: Where did he say he thought integers were stored in decimal?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He didn't. It follows from `strcat(buff, (char *) ptr);`.

Comment: @H2CO3: I really don't see how.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh wait, I was wrong. Whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you missed `&` operator.
Please try this:

```
v=(uint8_t *)&datum->data.i;
```

And never use `strcat` for binary data. It's for strings. Binary data should be handled with something like `memcpy`.

Comment: That does the trick :) Was focussing too much on the parts beneath it. Thank you very much! Works for ints and floats!
Ok, I will remember to use memcpy for binary data.